# after unsubscribe can't able to subscribe again in stripe gateway in php

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Here is my unsubscribe function

```
    public function cancelSubscription($ssid)
     {
    try {
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(SSK);

        $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve($ssid);
        if ($subscription['status'] == 'canceled') {
            return $subscription['status'];
        }
        $subscription->cancel();
        return $subscription;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($e->getMessage());
        echo '</pre>';
        die('error!- customer');
    }
}
```

Its working fine but when I am trying to upgrade my plan or trying to subscribe again I am getting an error.

> No such subscription:sub_EMYom4xxxxx

seems subscription id doesn't match after unsubscribe.
Please suggest any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well I would assume that subscribing automatically creates a subscription id, so you probably need to _not_ pass a subscription ID in that step, instead of passing one you previously explicitly “destroyed” by unsubscribing ...

Answer (score 4):

You can't reactivate a subscription after explicitly canceling it. If you mark it for cancelation you have a window to "un-cancel" before the cancelation date hits.

In this case you are canceling immediately so you'd need to create a new subscription entirely. See https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/canceling-pausing#pausing-a-subscription